# Ругается на конструкцию if

Tags: php

Почему выдаёт ошибку Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)?

```
foreach ($files as $f) {
            if(pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'json') {
              echo '<li>' . $f . ' <a href="'.
                        if(isset($_GET['del'])){
                          unlink('./test/test' . $_GET['del'] . '.json');
                        }. '">Удалить</a></li>';
        }

};
```

Хочу что бы удалялся тот файл, который будет передан параметром get.

Answer (score 1):

Так исправьте.

```
foreach ($files as $f) {
  if(pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'json') {
     echo '<li>' . $f . ' <a href="';

            if(isset($_GET['del'])) {
               unlink('./test/test' . $_GET['del'] . '.json');
            }

      echo  '">Удалить</a></li>';
    }
};
```

Comment: не помогло https://pastebin.com/cnuyrgJ0

Comment: Почему вы открыли тег <?php не закрывая предыдущего?

Comment: Поздно уже ( ерунду написал. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать, что бы удалялось после нажатия на ссылку?

Comment: Должно компилироваться, только логика непонятна.

Comment: Это совсем за рамки вопроса выходит. Надо использовать ajax.

Comment: ну как-то же можно на чистом php

Comment: Нельзя. Кнопка нажимается в браузере. Событие click отрабатывает javascript. Оттуда делается вызов php-скрипта на сервере, который удаляет файл.

Comment: Я сделал очень простым способ, что бы в get параметр подставлялось   название файла https://pastebin.com/W3QL28dE

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56477/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-divman).

Comment: Я бы рад, но мне некогда, а тут чат есть?

Comment: ))) Это автоматический комментарий системы, когда обсуждение выносится в чат. Тут не приветствуются длинные флеймы.